# Exclude file from search but not from the project list in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm

I've succeeded to exclude bower components and node modules from my search results by choosing the folder -> mark directory as -> excluded, but I couldn't do the the same for my concat file (a file with all code of the js files of my project).

How can I exclude this file from my search results?

Answer (score 18):

`Edit | Find | Find in Path` supports scopes. You can create a new scope (`Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Scopes`) with the generated file excluded and use this scope for searching. Or, place your generated file(s) into a separate folder and exclude it like you did for bower_components and node_modules

Edit: since 2017.2 you can exclude files by pattern - see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.2/directories.html, Exclude files

Comment: how can you just exclude all the log files that are generated. They don't show for me in that view

Comment: This is far from a proper solution to the problem listed in OP. The idea is hide a specific file without renaming it, moving it or modifying it in any other way.

Answer (score 4):

You can exclude files and folders by name pattern. Just follow the steps here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/excluding-files-from-project.html#exclude-by-pattern

Answer (score 2):

Man, use Preferences => Directories and thats it!
[image]

Comment: Files, not directories. You can't "Mark a file as excluded" for some reason. I wouldn't mark my whole "src" folder as excluded just so yarn.lock doesn't show up in search results